# ASPX - linking HTML pages to ASPX pages and responsive

Tags: html, asp.net, responsive

I have made a website thats responsive however we have a 3rd party team who are working on a database and pages within ASPX which allows us to update course pages (we run a qualifications based company)

is there anyway to make the ASPX pages responsive. At the moment I have the website going full width using margin 0 auto etc however the 3rd party is stating that ASPX cannot be responsive and cannot go full width across the page (hope that makes sense)

Is this true? Does anybody know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can make responsive website with web forms.
There are several articles on the web which will help you. The core idea is to ensure that the concepts of CSS which are needed to make website responsive are included in implementation like

- Media Queries
- Float left right and fluid width on containers

You can also include CSS responsive libraries like Bootstrap to your application design.

See these links:

- [Building beautiful, responsive sites with Bootstrap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bootstrap)
- [Create an ASP.NET Web Forms Application using Bootstrap and Web API](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815916/Create-an-ASP-NET-Web-Forms-Application-using-Boot)

Core idea is that you use Bootstrap styles on your ASPX web form elements to make them responsive.

Comment: Perfect! thank you - thought it was possible however I wanted proof from various people / articles to send over to the other developer

Comment: @Callum Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.